# I am unable to publish pbxi file to group work space

Tags: powerbi, publish

an error occurred while attempting to publish .pbxi. unable to write data to the transport connection: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

tried all things but could not find the problem

Comment: Check the size of the .pbxi file: If the file is very large, it may take a long time to upload, and the connection may time out. Try compressing the file into a .zip or .tar.gz archive to reduce its size.